# compare everything except the first field with awk

Tags: linux

I want to compare word except first field from the file by awk command.

example:

```
echo $var xyz
```

cat file.txt

```
/home/abc/pqr xyz test
/home/abc/pqr mnp qsf xyz
/home/abc/pqr ngc prj txt
```

So output will be

```
/home/abc/pqr xyz test
/home/abc/pqr mnp qsf xyz
```

currently I am using following command to compare with only second filed.

```
awk -v var="$var" '{if($2==var){print > "compare.txt"}}' file.txt;
```

But now I want to compare variable with all field except first field

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the most elegant solution, but it works:

```
awk -v var="xyz" '{for(i=1; i <= NF; i++){if($i==var){print ; break}}}' file.txt
```